# Ansible playbook and return values during a failure

Tags: ansible

I have an ansible playbook as below, the objective is to run a ping check across a number of hosts, and the playbook should return if the ping was successful or not per host. This works by running a ping on a windows host to ascertain connectivity, the status of the connectivity is then passed onto a powershell script. The powershell script will record the result for analysis.

What I want the script to now do is report back if connectivity fails for a particular host, at the moment with the playbook, if host connectivity fails, the entire playbook errors. The idea is that if i have 10 hosts, and connectivity fails for 2 and works for 8 hosts, the failed ping response should be returned to the powershell script for 2 hosts, and 8 hosts should send a return value of connection successful to the powershell script.

```
---
  - name: Get host facts
    set_fact:
      serverdomain: "{{ansible_domain}}"
      server_ip: "{{ansible_ip_addresses[1]}}"

  - name: Host Ping Check
    ignore_errors: yes
    win_ping:
    register: var_ping

  - name: Get Host name
    debug: msg="{{the_host_name}}"
  
  - name: Set Execution File and parameters
    set_fact:
      scriptfile: "{{ansible_user_dir}}\\scripts\\host_check.ps1"
      params: "-servername '{{the_host_name}}' -response var_ping.failed"
  
  - name: Execute script
    win_command: powershell.exe "{{scriptfile}}" "{{params}}"
```

Comment: if I understood it correctly, you need a `ignore_errors: true` for your `win_ping` module. Can you add that right below your `register: var_ping` and test it?

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `ignore_errors: true` as this is [almost always an issue](https://ansible-lint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/default_rules.html#ignore-errors) but instead use `failed_when: false`.

Make use of `when:` to condition execution based of what `var_ping` contains, likely you want to print it before to figure out what it contains in each execution path.